# Insert &times; using CSS pseudo element

Tags: css, special-characters, pseudo-element

I am trying to use × &times HTML character as a close icon on a dialog link

```
.close:before {
    content: "\0274c";
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Firefox works with the example above and also using

```
content: "\274c";
```

Chrome wont accept either and simply gives me a missing character square. I am using Arial as the font. What do I need to do to make this cross browser compatible?

Comment: `content: "\d7";` ?

Comment: That did the ticket though for some reason is much smaller than what I had. I can adjust the font size though. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Works fine for me!
Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 36.0.1985.125 m on Windows

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The escape sequence you're using does not represent the `&times;` sign. It represents U+274C CROSS MARK, which is an entirely different symbol altogether (and one that happens to be represented in emoji as well).

The codepoint of ×, as mentioned in the comments, is U+00D7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN, which is what you are looking for. The difference in size boils down to how each character glyph is drawn in the typeface.

If a browser does not render U+274C (or any other given character for that matter), it may be an issue with either the font, or the browser, or even the platform.

Comment: So you mean that 

content: "U+00D7"; 

Should work otherwise it is the fault of the font or browser?

Comment: @Rachel Reveley: Sorry for the confusion - the syntax in CSS is `content: "\00d7"` or `content: "\d7"` as in Alex's comment. Either one should work, in this case Chrome just seems to be having trouble with the cross mark and not the times sign.

Answer (score 1):

You could use other symbols:

- U+2716   - HEAVY MULTIPLICATION
- U+1F5D9  - CANCELLATION

For more options see: [X mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark)

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the close icon as per the [boostrap recommendations](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/close-icon/) and wanted the code to be reusable, so decided to use the 'x' icon configured in css itself. The following code worked fine for me:

```
.close-icon-right:after {
   content: '\00D7';
   position: absolute;
   right: 1rem;
   top: 1rem;
}
```

As rightly pointed by @BoltClock, "U+00D7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN" is sign for multiplication and can be used as `content: '\00D7'` in the css pseudo class.